# How can I get exactly 5 logarithmic divisions of an interval?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, logarithmic-scale

I'd like to get exactly 5 divisions from *x* to *y* on a log scale. Can `FindDivisions` do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After 3 years, it has been discovered that this oft-linked-to answer doesn't truly space logarithmically. It's close, which was all I was going for at the time (and handles zeros), but it's not quite right. Anyway, thanks to @Pickett's careful moderation, here's a better version...

```
logspace[increments_, start_?Positive, end_?Positive] :=
 Exp@Range[Log@start, Log@end, Log[end/start]/increments]
```

This one, by the stodgy nature of Logs, won't handle non-positive numbers, so I'll leave the old answer. Sorry to all that lost millions in the stock market using the old function. :)

**OLD FUNCTION**

I built a function that calculates log spaced increments for a job at work. I've added a catch where it will handle log spacing from 0 to a number.

```
logspace [increments_, start_, end_] := Module[{a}, (
   a = Range[0, increments];
   Exp[a/increments*Log[(end - start) + 1]] - 1 + start
   )]
```

To try it out:

```
N@logspace[5,1,1000]

(*{1., 3.98107, 15.8489, 63.0957, 251.189, 1000.}*)
```

To view it on a number line:

```
a = N@logspace[10, 0, 10];
Graphics[Point@Transpose[{a, ConstantArray[.5, 11]}], Axes -> {True, False}, 
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.05]]
```

[image]

And if you want to find the distances between divisions, use `Differences`:

```
Differences[a]

(*{0.270982, 0.344413, 0.437742, 0.556362, 0.707126, 0.898744, 1.14229, 1.45183, 1.84524, 2.34527}*)
```

Comment: A problem (I think?) with this function was discovered, please see the comments [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94648/731).

Comment: @Pickett Oh dear. I wrote that 3 years ago (about the amount of time I've used MMA).... eek. Yeah, it log-ish spaces, but isn't a "true" logspace. Let me work on that...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! :)

Comment: So how to get the logspace from -1 to 2?

Answer (score 24):

Writing one wouldn't be that hard. You can convert it to `Log10` and then let `FindDivisions` do all the work in log space before converting it back. For example:

```
findLogDivisions[{xmin_, xmax_}, n_Integer] := 10^FindDivisions[Log10@{xmin, xmax}, n]
```

Then, to find 4 "nice" divisions in log space between 1 and 1000, you simply need to do:

```
findLogDivisions[{1, 1000}, 5] 
(* {1, 10, 100, 1000} *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a mathematically simple approach, assuming that *exactly* `n` divisions are sought, no matter how nice or not.

This produces exactly `n` intervals:

```
Clear[logDiv];
logDiv[{x_?Positive, y_?Positive}, n_Integer /; n > 0] := 
  x (y/x)^Range[0, 1, 1/n]

logDiv[{10, 10000}, 3]
(* {10, 100, 1000, 10000} *)
```

If you want `n` "fence posts", use

```
Clear[logDiv];
logDiv[{x_?Positive, y_?Positive}, n_Integer /; n > 1] := 
  x (y/x)^Range[0, 1, 1/(n-1)]
```

If you want `n` *interior* division points, change `n` to `n+1` in the first version.

---

*Comparisons.*  Kuba's method produces the same output as `logDiv` *mutatis mutandis*​*.  Below I use the first version of `logDiv` and omit Kuba's output.

Comparison 1:

```
N @ logDiv[{1/10, 100000}, 3]           (* same output as Kuba *)
N @ logspace[3, 1/10, 100000]           (* kale *)
N @ findLogDivisions[{1/10, 100000}, 3] (* rm -rf *)
(*
  {0.1, 10., 1000., 100000.}
  {0.1, 45.516, 2153.55, 100000.}
  {0.01, 1., 100., 10000., 1.*10^6}
*)
```

Comparison 2:

```
N @ logDiv[{10, 100000}, 5]
N @ logspace[5, 10, 100000]
N @ findLogDivisions[{10, 100000}, 5]
(*
  {10., 63.0957, 398.107, 2511.89, 15848.9, 100000.}
  {10., 18.9998, 108.996, 1008.95, 10008.3, 100000.}
  {10., 100., 1000., 10000., 100000.}
*)
```

Note the outputs vary; in particular `logspace` does something quite different than the others when `start` is different than `1`.  Depending on the application, one or the other might be desired.

---

*In honor of the [language survey](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/mathematica-se-human-language-survey).

Comment: +1, what do you think about editing the question. Now the answer `RandomReal[{start, end}, 5]` fits quite well.

Comment: +1 to you, too.  I'm assuming `RandomReal` is a joke :)  However the question could more clearly state what exactly counts as a division.  It seems to me the OP should decide, but it's not a big deal.  I wish the OP had accepted or commented on the other answers, though.

Comment: Yes it is a joke but it fits :) Maybe it's better with it's vague form, more answers are valid.

Answer (score 6):

I do a lot of work where I need to have function evaluations at equal logarithmic spacings.  The code I use is

```
GeometricRange[imin_, imax_, perRange[n_]] := GeometricRange[imin, imax, 
  (imax/imin)^(1/(n - 1))]; 
GeometricRange[imin_, imax_, r_] := Exp[Range @@ Log[N[{imin, imax, r}]]]; 
perDecade[n_] := 10^(1/(n - 1)); 
perOctave[n_] := 2^(1/(n - 1));
```

`GeometricRange` has the same calling syntax as `Range`, where the increment (in this case, the ratio `r`) is given as an argument, but also has the option of specifying the total number of samples in the range with `perRange` or commonly used log resolutions with `perDecade` or `perOctave`.  The calling syntax is

```
In[10]:= GeometricRange[10, 1000, 10]
Out[10]= {10., 100., 1000.}
```

or

```
In[9]:=GeometricRange[10, 1000, 10 // perRange]
Out[9]= {10., 16.681, 27.8256, 46.4159, 77.4264, 129.155, 215.443, 359.381, 599.484, 1000.}
```

or

```
In[6]:= GeometricRange[10, 1000, 10 // perDecade]
Out[6]= {10., 12.9155, 16.681, 21.5443, 27.8256, 35.9381, 46.4159,
59.9484, 77.4264, 100., 129.155, 166.81, 215.443, 278.256, 359.381,
464.159, 599.484, 774.264, 1000.}
```

Here is the complete code for Version 10 and up, using `PowerRange`

```
perDecade[(n_)?Positive] := 10^(1/(n - 1)); 
perOctave[(n_)?Positive] := 2^(1/(n - 1)); 
perRange /: PowerRange[imin_, imax_, perRange[(n_Integer)?Positive]] := 
  PowerRange[imin, imax, (imax/imin)^(1/(n - 1))];
```

Comment: As of version 10.0, GeometricRange can be replaced by the built-in function PowerRange.

Answer (score 5):

`Array` may be used just like [here by rm -rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32721/5478) but only for [V9 or later version: see this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38011/5478)

```
10^Array[# &, 6, Log10@{1., 1000}]
```

> ```
> {1., 3.98107, 15.8489, 63.0957, 251.189, 1000.}
> ```