# Is there a Mathematica equivalent to MATLAB's logspace?

Tags: list-manipulation, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get exactly 5 logarithmic divisions of an interval?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13226/how-can-i-get-exactly-5-logarithmic-divisions-of-an-interval)

I want to use `Table` to generate a list of items, but want the indices to be logarithmically spaced. Is there a simple way of doing this, or will I have to explicitly run linearly spaced indices through `Exp` to get my list?

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13226/5

Comment: Its asked in a different way though...more general for a start and it is targetted towards MATLABers. Personally i'd have left this up.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a somewhat simpler way:

```
 logspace[a_, b_, n_] := 10.0^Range[a, b, (b - a)/(n - 1)]
```

This gives a sequence starting at `10^a` and ending at `10^b`, with `n` points logarithmically spaced, as does MATLAB's `logspace()` function.

Answer (score 10):

I don't belive there is a build in function for this, however you can easily do it using Range

```
 fSpace[min_, max_, steps_, f_: Log] :=  
      InverseFunction[f] /@ Range[f@min, f@max, (f@max - f@min)/(steps - 1)]
```

Inverse functions are being used so it'll give warnings in cases where you should be cautius, however it works for Log and other invertible functions.

```
 fSpace[1, 1000, 4]
```

> {1, 10, 100, 1000}

```
{fSpace[1, 1000, 30, Sqrt[#] &], fSpace[1, 1000, 30]} // ListPlot
```

[image: Image showing both logspacing and Sqrt spacing]

**Update**

I just discovered that you can in fact do even better out of the box by inverting the function only on the input range:

```
 fSpace[min_, max_, steps_, f_: Log] := 
  InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[f[#], min < # < max] &] /@ 
  Range[f@min, f@max, (f@max - f@min)/(steps - 1)]
```

This still doesn't work arbitrarily, however it does help for instance selecting the positive square root in `#^2&`.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I wanted!