# Is there an equivalent to MATLAB's linspace?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matlab

Does *Mathematica* have an equivalent to Matlab's `linspace`? I want to make a list with "start", "stop" and "number of points". What is the neatest way of doing this?

Answer (score 31):

There was an update for `Array`, not done to the end. The method below does not work for earlier versions even though that `Array` is

> New in 1 | Last modified in 4

Moreover WRI forgot to update docs for error messages: [Array::plen](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Array/plen.html) - the first example gives no error in V9.

### V9

> ```
> Array[# &, n, {start, stop}]
> ```

```
Array[# &, 10, {-1, 1}]
```

> ```
> {-1, -(7/9), -(5/9), -(1/3), -(1/9), 1/9, 1/3, 5/9, 7/9, 1}
> ```

### V<9

```
ClearAll[linespace];
linespace[s_, f_, 1] := (f + s)/2
linespace[s_, f_, n_] := Range[s, f, (f - s)/(n - 1)]
```

---

Comment: Nice, this one I´ll crib shamelessly :D

Comment: I like Array, work like charm

Comment: I've written `Range[s, f, (f - s)/(n - 1)]` so many times that my fingers run across the keyboard on their own

Comment: Daaamn... I should've answered this question instead of the dupe. I answered the exact same question 3 months ago with the same answer and got only 2 votes :P

Comment: can you have a code example?

Comment: @CharlieParker what do you mean?

Comment: If you get around to updating this: from 10.1 onwards you can now do `Subdivide[-1, 1, 10 - 1]`.

Comment: @J.M. yep, though it is already mentioned in the parent thread.

Answer (score 6):

You could use table... unless I am missing something really basic. Speed, maybe?
Edited to consider the special case as suggested by Kuba.

```
linspace[start_, stop_, n_:100] := Table[x, {x, start, stop, (stop - start)/(n - 1)}]
linspace[start_, stop_, 1] := Mean[{start,stop}]
```

Comment: it is the way too, be careful with `n=1`.

Comment: Ah, ok. My procedures are written with the implicit disclaimer "this will help you aim at your foot, it's up to you not to pull the trigger". Well, it can be overloaded to consider the special case.

Comment: I like this disclaimer :) but notice that I'm not reminding about negative numbers, strings etc. but about little function deficiency.

Comment: I certainly appreciate feedback. So, basically, this special case could arise within some automated task that could compute the number of points and come up with the special, and apparently useless case n=1. Before writing my post I had a look at the web documentation for linspace for MATLAB and this special case is not mentioned. Actually, I see now this http://cens.ioc.ee/local/man/matlab/techdoc/ref/linspace.html is the first page that came up but it appears it is not on Mathworks servers. So my bad for not checking it thoroughly.

Comment: it seems there is no good answer :) `n=1` seems useless but on the other hand, why not?