# Creating a custom list

Tags: list-manipulation

This is the first list

```
lts1 = Table[i, {i, -1.8, 5.8, 0.1}]
```

1st question: In the interval between -1.8 and 5,8 how can I choose the step beforehand so as the list to contain 100 elements?

The second list

```
dist = MixtureDistribution[{1, 2}, {NormalDistribution[1, 1/2], 
NormalDistribution[4, 5/3]}]
lst2 = RandomVariate[dist, 10^2]
```

We know that the second list contains 100 elements.

2st question: How can I join these two lists so the new list to be 
`{{lst1[[1]], lst2[[1]]}, {lst1[[2]], lst2[[2]]}, ..., {lst1[[100]], lst2[[100]]}}`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [32715](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32715/5478) / [38009](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38009/5478) + `Transpose`.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it seems to me of limited general usefulness. The first part of your question is not quite about *Mathematica*, but rather about how generally to find divisions of an interval. For the second part of your question, instead, take a look at the "Transpose and dimensions" section at the beginning of the following answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/27951.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1) try `step = (b-a)/(n-1)`, in your case

```
step = (5.8 - -1.8)/99;
lts1 = Table[i, {i, -1.8, 5.8, step}];
Length @ lts1

(* 100 *)
```

For (2) you just need

```
Transpose[{lts1,lst2}]
```