# Calibrating the length of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose you want to create a uniform square grid of initial conditions on the (x,y) plane. This can be done using

```
s = 2;
step = 0.01;
data = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -s, s, step}, {j, -s, s, step}], 1];
ICs = Length[data]
```

Now my question is rather simple. How can I adjust the `step` so as the `Length` of the list to be equal to `N`, let's say `N = 1000`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really a MMA question, to set the side length of your square grid to N, then use `step = 2s/(N-1)`.

Comment: But as Kuba says, you'll have a problem if you want to the the overall length of your flattened list to a non-square number. (As you'd have to use different step sizes in the i and j directions).

Comment: [32715](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32715/5478) [38009](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38009/5478)

Comment: Since `N@Array[ic, Sqrt[100] {1, 1}, {{-s, s}, {-s, s}}] // Flatten // Length` works, then it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli I run several tests with the code proposed yesterday regarding the basins of attraction and the results seem free of obvious errors. I have in mind another type of plot and I really want your ideas on how to modify the code for this specific plot.

Answer (score 1):

```
In[55]:= stp[len_] := NSolve[(2./step1)*2 + 1 == Sqrt[len], step1]

In[56]:= stp[160801.]

Out[56]= {{step1 -> 0.01}}

In[57]:= stp[10000]

Out[57]= {{step1 -> 0.040404}}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have `Range` and `Table` which require specifying the step size, and not the final list length (unlike MATLAB's `linspace`).  Version 10.1 introduces the convenience function `Subdivide` which takes the number of intervals `n` into which the input interval will be subdivided.  Thus it gives `n+1` points.

You can generate an `n` by `m` grid using

```
Tuples[{Subdivide[xmin, xmax, n-1], Subdivide[ymin, ymax, m-1]}]
```

This is a sort of an analog of using `linspace` with `meshgrid` in MATLAB.  I had the impression that you were looking for something like that.

Comment: Any suggestion for those stuck in v9.0?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z yep, take a look at links I've included.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z `Subdivide` is really just a convenience function which can easily be re-implemented in terms of `Range`.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 2;
len = 100;

data =
 Table[{i, j}, {i, -s, s, (s - -s)/(len - 1)}, {j, -s, s, (s - -s)/(len - 1)}];

Dimensions@data
```

> {100, 100, 2}

Generalization

```
MakeGrid[{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}, {xn_, yn_}] :=
 Table[{x, y}, {x, x1, x2, (x2 - x1)/(xn - 1)}, {y, y1, y2, (y2 - y1)/(yn - 1)}]

MakeGrid[{2, 4}, {1, 3}, {50, 100}] // Dimensions
```

> {50, 100, 2}