# How do I place points along the curves in a plot?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to place points on these functions

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[{a^x, b^x}, {x, -10, 10},
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 15}}], 
  {a, 3, 10, 1}, 
  {b, 2, 11, 1}, 
  {c, 3, 10, 1}]
```

and control the number of points along the function with a slider using manipulate. I've managed to write out this function, somehow, but I'm relatively new to *Mathematica* and don't know where to start.

For example, when the 3rd slider is at 0, there should be 0 points. When its at 1, there should be 1 point in the middle of the graph. This should change to 2 evenly spaced points on each function when the slider is 2, and so on.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38011/5478) + `Epilog` + `Point`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `Mesh` to add points on the curve:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[{a^x, b^x}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 15}}, 
          Mesh -> 2 p, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]], {a, 3, 10, 1}, 
          {b, 2, 11, 1}, {{p, 4}, 0, 100, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Beat me to it!  From the OP's description, I would set it to `Mesh->2p` so that when `p=2` there are 2 points on each curve.

Comment: @JasonB, good point. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful.

Comment: @RileyMorgan. You're welcome, glad I could help.