# Base 2 Tick Labels for ListLogLogPlot

Tags: ticks, logarithmic-scale, labeling

I am using `ListLogLogPlot` and would like to express the x-axis tick labels in powers of 2 instead of the default powers of 10. Does anybody have experience with this? Here is my code thus far:

```
mylist = 
  {{2^1024, 10^-307}, {2^512, 10^-153}, {2^256, 10^-76}, {2^128, 10^-38}, {2^64,10^-18},
   {2^32, 10^-9}, {2^16, 10^-4}};

ListLogLogPlot[mylist,
  PlotLabel -> Style["H field to break Subscript[Z, 2] symmetry (HN5)", FontSize -> 18],
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.015]},
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{1, 10^335}, {10^-320, 10^0}},
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Size, N", FontSize -> 18],
  Style["H", FontSize -> 24]}, RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using and expanding [rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf) function from [How can I get exactly 5 logarithmic divisions of an interval?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13226/5478)

```
findLogDivisions[{xmin_, xmax_}, n_Integer, b_: 10] := {
                           b^#, HoldForm[b^#]} & /@ FindDivisions[Log[b, {xmin, xmax}], n]

ListLogLogPlot[mylist, Ticks -> {(findLogDivisions[{#, #2}, 7, 2] &), Automatic}]
```

[image]

For `findLogDivisions[{#, #2}, 7, Pi]`:

[image]

Comment: useful function, will have to  add +1 :)

Comment: All of these answers were very helpful, and I like how generalized this one is. Thank you everybody for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way. I have not used titles. I have just used ticks from the dataset but placed the first tick on top frame to avoid crowding. There are other ways but I hope this provides motivation to achieve the ticks and layout you want.

```
mylist = {{2^1024, 10^-307}, {2^512, 10^-153}, {2^256, 
    10^-76}, {2^128, 10^-38}, {2^64, 10^-18}, {2^32, 10^-9}, {2^16, 
    10^-4}};
tcks = {#, 
     StringForm["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(`1`\)]\)", 
      Log[2, #]]} & /@ mylist[[All, 1]];
ListLogLogPlot[mylist, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {Rest@Sort[tcks], Automatic, {First@Sort[tcks]}, None},
  PlotStyle -> Red, BaseStyle -> {12, PointSize[0.02], Blue}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not an ideal solution unless you are ok with the x tick location being the same as data.

```
mylist = {{2^1024, 10^-307}, {2^512, 10^-153}, {2^256, 10^-76}, 
    {2^128, 10^-38}, {2^64, 10^-18}, {2^32, 10^-9}, {2^16, 10^-4}};

 ticks[min_, max_] := 
  Table[{z = N@Log[mylist[[i, 1]]]/Log[2]; mylist[[i, 1]], Style[Rotate[2^ToString[z],
      Pi/2], 16], {.01, 0.0}, Red}, {i, Length[mylist]}];


ListLogLogPlot[
 mylist,
 PlotLabel -> Style["H field to break Subscript[Z, 2] symmetry (HN5)", FontSize -> 18],
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.015]},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{1, 10^335}, {10^-320, 10^0}},
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Size, N", 18], Style["H", 24]},
 RotateLabel -> False, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {ticks, Automatic}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I wish Mathematica would pass the tick location to the user, so that the user can just change the labels.

Comment: I agree customizable tick positions would be nice...I dealt with crowding by moving tick label to top frame...not ideal I guess

Comment: @ubpdqn lets hope in V 10 they made it more easy to change the tick labels !

Comment: agreed...looking forward to v.10...still no real understanding of Wolfram Language means but some very interesting hints/previews around...

Answer (score 0):

My answer is along a similar vein as those by @ubpdqn and @Nasser, but I thought it would be easier to control the spacing of the labels by switching it to `ListPlot` and dealing with the logs manually. You can then either use the normal output of the min and max from `Ticks` to set the limits or set the top, bottom and the increment manually.  I provide a blended example which sets the top of the y and the right of the x based upon the `Ticks` and the rest set as variables so that you could optimize the figure prior to finalizing.

```
    Clear["Global`*"];
    mylist = {{2^1024, 10^-307}, {2^512, 10^-153}, {2^256, 
        10^-76}, {2^128, 10^-38}, {2^64, 10^-18}, {2^32, 10^-9}, {2^16, 
        10^-4}};

    mylist2 = {Log[2, #1], Log[10, #2]} & @@@ mylist;

    log2min = 128;
    log2inc = 256;
    log10max = -40;
    log10inc = 40;

    myticks2[min_, max_] := 
      Table[{x, Superscript[2, x]}, {x, log2min, max, log2inc}];
    myticks10[min_, max_] := 
      Table[{x, Superscript[10, x]}, {x, min, log10max, log10inc}];

    ListPlot[mylist2, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Style["H field to break Subscript[Z, 2] symmetry (HN5)", 
       FontSize -> 18], PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.015]}, 
     FrameTicks -> {{myticks10, None}, {myticks2, None}}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1280}, {-320, 0}}, 
     FrameLabel -> {Style["Size, N", FontSize -> 18], 
       Style["H", FontSize -> 24]}, RotateLabel -> False]
```

I decided that it would be nice to be able to interactively `Manipulate` the various values, including changing the the base for the log function.  Here is that version.

```
    Clear["Global`*"]; 
    Manipulate[
     mylist = {{2^1024, 10^-307}, {2^512, 10^-153}, {2^256, 
        10^-76}, {2^128, 10^-38}, {2^64, 10^-18}, {2^32, 10^-9}, {2^16, 
        10^-4}};

     mylist2 = {Log[scaleX, #1], Log[scaleY, #2]} & @@@ mylist; 
     myticksX = 
      Table[{x, Superscript[scaleX, x]}, {x, logXmin, logXmax, logXinc}];
     myticksY = 
      Table[{x, Superscript[scaleY, x]}, {x, logYmin, logYmax, logYinc}];

     ListPlot[mylist2, 
      PlotLabel -> 
       Style["H field to break Subscript[Z, 2] symmetry (HN5)", 
        FontSize -> 18], PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.015]}, 
      FrameTicks -> {{myticksY, None}, {myticksX, None}}, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1280}, {-320, 0}}, 
      FrameLabel -> {Style["Size, N", FontSize -> 18], 
        Style["H", FontSize -> 24]}, RotateLabel -> False],
     {{scaleX, 2, "Log Scale For X-Axis"}, 2, 16, 1},
     {{scaleY, 10, "Log Scale For Y-Axis"}, 2, 16, 1},
     Delimiter,
     {{logXmin, 256, "Minimum for X-Axis"}, 0, 2048},
     {{logXmax, 2048, "Maximum for X-Axis"}, 0, 2048},
     {{logXinc, 256, "Increment for X-Axis"}, 32, 2048, 32},
     {{logYmin, -320, "Minimum for Y-Axis"}, -360, -300, 1},
     {{logYmax, -40, "Maximum for Y-Axis"}, 0, -80, 1},
     {{logYinc, 40, "Increment for Y-Axis"}, 1, 300, 10}, 
     ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]