# Label x-axis of Plot with power of two values

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I want to make a plot similar to LogLinearPlot, but with power of 2 ticks instead of 10 on x axis.

```
values = {n -> 2^x}
Plot[{Evaluate[f[n] /. values]}, {x, 2, 10}]
```

How to mark x axis with 2^2, 2^3, ... , 2^10 instead of default 2, 3, ..., 10 ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. How about this? `Plot[{2^x}, {x, 2, 10}, Ticks -> {Range[2, 10], 2^Range[2, 10]}]`

Comment: 1) see the help for `Ticks` and `StandardForm` 2) Be careful and don't use names starting with Capital letters ... they are used by Mma itself (See also the help for `N[]`)

Comment: to belisarius - that is an important note about capital letters, changed N to n to avoid unnecessary confusion.

Comment: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44554/base-2-tick-labels-for-listloglogplot) is a similar question for ListLogLogPlot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For illustrative purposes:

```
DiscretePlot[x, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {Table[{j, 
     Style[Superscript[2, j], ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {0.15}, 
      ScriptBaselineShifts -> {0, 1}]}, {j, 10}], Automatic, None, 
   None}, BaseStyle -> 16, 
 PlotLabel -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(2\)]\)(n)"]
```

[image]

I added the options `ScriptSizeMultipliers` and `ScriptBaselineShifts` to illustrate the customizability of appearance (i.e. feel free to play with).