# Logarithmic x-axis for ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list of points that I am trying to plot.  Is there a way to make a `ListPlot` where the y-axis increases normally by 1 every interval but the x-axis increases by $x^2$, i.e., 1, 4, 9, 16, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44554/5478), unfortunately my answer doesn't seem to work in V10.

Comment: of course the requested power law interval is not logarithmic. You ought to edit the question or title to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely what `ListLogLinearPlot` achieves--logarithmic $x$ and linear $y$ axes:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 100}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make custom ticks and transform the data:

```
 list = Table[ {x, Log[x]} , {x, 1, 25} ];
 ListPlot[{Sqrt[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ list , 
               Ticks -> {{#, #^2} & /@ Range[1, 5], Automatic} ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can define your own ticks marks when you do the plot.

```
   data = Table[{i, i}, {i, 1, 50, 1}]
   SpecialTicks = Table[{i^2, i}, {i, 1, 50, 1}];
   ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {SpecialTicks, All}}]
```

[image]

Here, I've added "All" just to show the linear tick marks at the top of the graph, but you can remove them.

Comment: I changed from ListLinePlot to ListLogLinearPlot but it didn't connect the data points anymore. So I had to add ,Joined -> True. I also had to fiddle with axis origin to remove a vertical line that appeared.