# data manipulation in log-log scale

Tags: function-construction, data, matlab

Say that I have the following:

```
y[t_] := 2 + (2/10)*(1 - Exp[-t/11])

timedat = N[Table[{t, y[t]}, {t, 0, 10, 1/1000}]];
```

How is it possible to construct an algorithm that it will pick data uniformly spaced in log time from a set of data uniformly spaced in time, as the above `timedat`?

Basically, what I want is the Mathematica counterpart of the following Matlab algorithm

```
% log sampling, user picks the initial time and increment time
% xi(:,1) time (equally spaced in time)
% xi(:,2) compliance
ndp = length(xi(:,1)); %# data points read
tf = xi(ndp,1); %final time
logti = -1; %log of initial time to sample, user choice
del_logti = 0.1; %log time interval to sample, user choice
logt = [logti:del_logti:log10(tf)]; %equally spaced in log scale
tr = 10.^logt; %back to time scale
nr = length(tr); %number of newly sampled data
if tr(nr)~=tf;
tr = [tr,tf]; %add the final time
nr = length(tr); %number of newly sampled data
end
rcount = 1;
for i=1:ndp
if xi(i,1) >= tr(rcount) %say 10^-0.1
xo(rcount,:) = xi(i,:); %copy data equally spaced in log(time)
rcount = rcount+1;
end
if rcount > nr, break, end;
end
```

which I found [here](http://barbero.cadec-online.com/papers/2010/10Guedes(Ed.)ISBN978-1-84569-525-5Chapter2Barbero.pdf) ; page 4.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How can I get exactly 5 logarithmic divisions of an interval?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13226/how-can-i-get-exactly-5-logarithmic-divisions-of-an-interval/)

Comment: @Pickett: Thanks a lot for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Range`, `Length`, `Nearest`, `Flatten`, `Select` and `MemberQ` you can extract uniformly spaced log time from your uniformly spaced in time data.

First an example is shown using 0.1 for the minimum time, 10.0 for the maximum time and 21 for the number of samples.

Then it will be wrapped up into a function.

Data is generated as in your question.

```
y[t_] := 2 + (2/10)*(1 - Exp[-t/11])
timedat = N[Table[{t, y[t]}, {t, 0, 10, 1/1000}]];
```

Evenly spaced logarithmic time is created from 0.1 to 10 in 21 steps.

```
equalLogTime = Range[Log[0.1], Log[10], (Log[10] - Log[0.1])/(21 - 1)]
```

{-2.30259, -2.07233, -1.84207, -1.61181, -1.38155, -1.15129, 
-0.921034, -0.690776, -0.460517, -0.230259, 
 4.44089*10^-16, 0.230259, 0.460517, 0.690776, 0.921034, 1.15129, 
1.38155, 1.61181, 1.84207, 2.07233, 2.30259}

The evenly spaced logarithmic time is converted back to linear

```
equalTime = Exp[equalLogTime]
```

{0.1, 0.125893, 0.158489, 0.199526, 0.251189, 0.316228, 0.398107, 
0.501187, 0.630957, 0.794328, 1., 1.25893, 1.58489, 1.99526, 2.51189, 
3.16228, 3.98107, 5.01187, 6.30957, 7.94328, 10.}

The time from the `timedat` that are closest to these numbers are found.

```
timedatEqualTime = Flatten[Nearest[timedat[[All, 1]], #] & /@ equalTime]
```

{0.1, 0.126, 0.158, 0.2, 0.251, 0.316, 0.398, 0.501, 0.631, 0.794, 
1., 1.259, 1.585, 1.995, 2.512, 3.162, 3.981, 5.012, 6.31, 7.943, 10.}

`timedatEqualTime` is used to extract the {time, value} pairs from `timedat`

```
dataEvenLogTime = Select[timedat, MemberQ[timedatEqualTime, #[[1]]] &]
```

Now, putting it into a function:

```
extractEqualLogTime[data_, timeMin_, timeMax_, numberPoints_] := 
 Module[
  {
   equalLogTime,
   equalTime,
   dataEqualTime
   },

  equalLogTime = Range[Log[timeMin], Log[timeMax], 
    (Log[timeMax] - Log[timeMin])/(numberPoints - 1)];

  equalTime = Exp[equalLogTime];

  dataEqualTime = Flatten[Nearest[data[[All, 1]], #] & /@ equalTime];

  Select[data, MemberQ[dataEqualTime, #[[1]]] &]
  ]
```

Applying the function

```
dataEvenLogTime = extractEqualLogTime[timedat, 0.1, 10, 21]
```

Now it is plotted on a logarithmic time scale to validate the even spacing.

```
ListLogLinearPlot[dataEvenLogTime]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Where `timedat` is defined?

Comment: When I apply your function I get an error message `Nearest::dmtch: The dimension of ...does not match.` I guess sth I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `timedat` comes from your original question. `y[t_] := 2 + (2/10)*(1 - Exp[-t/11])` and then `timedat = N[Table[{t, y[t]}, {t, 0, 10, 1/1000}]]`. After executing those two statements and then copying the definition for `extractEqualLogTime` from the answer and executing `ListLogLinearPlot[dataEvenLogTime]` it should work. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding! Thank you one more time for your nice workaround.

Comment: For the sake of completeness. For versions prior to 10.1 one could try sth like `Flatten[Nearest[timedat[[All, 1]], equalTime[[#]]] & /@ 
  Range[Length[equalTime]]]` . The output is again the same; i.e. `{0.1, 0.126, 0.158, 0.2, 0.251, 0.316, 0.398, 0.501, 0.631, 0.794, \
1., 1.259, 1.585, 1.995, 2.512, 3.162, 3.981, 5.012, 6.31, 7.943, 10.}` . `Flatten@Nearest[timedat[[All, 1]], equalTime]` produces the error message `Nearest::dmtch: The dimension of ... does not match.` Unfortunately, `Nearest[data,{x1,x2,…}]` was introduced in version 10.1.

Comment: @dimitris Modified answer so that it would run with Version 9. Used your suggestion slightly modified `Flatten[Nearest[timedat[[All, 1]], #] & /@ equalTime]`

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm does two things:

1. Sample uniformly in log space and then convert it back to time space.
2. Select data points in time space corresponding to the samples generated in (1).

`logspace` from [[13226]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13234/731) can be used for (1):

```
logspace[increments_, start_?Positive, end_?Positive] :=
 Exp@Range[Log@start, Log@end, Log[end/start]/increments]
```

For step 2, `Nearest` is useful:

```
logSpaceSample[samplepoints_, datapoints_] := 
 First@*Nearest[First[#] -> # & /@ datapoints] /@ samplepoints
```

Example usage:

```
y[t_] := 2 + (2/10)*(1 - Exp[-t/11])

timedat = N[Table[{t, y[t]}, {t, 0, 10, 1/1000}]];

res = logSpaceSample[
   logspace[10, 1, 10],
   timedat
   ];

ex = {{First[#], 0} & /@ res, {Log@First[#], 1} & /@ res};
Graphics[{
  ColorData[97][1], Point@ex[[1]],
  ColorData[97][2], Point@ex[[2]]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may note that `logspace` does not take the same arguments for sampling that your algorithm does. It takes `increments` number of samples from `start` to `end`. You can rewrite it as you see fit.

Comment: I have Mathematica 10.0 and I do not appear to have `Subdivide`. Was it added later?

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens You are right, it was added in 10.1. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Pickett I like your answer but something is wrong with `logspace`. I compare the answers from `Exp@Range[Log[0.1], Log[10], (Log[10] - Log[0.1])/(21 - 1)]` with the output from `logspace[20, 0.1, 10]` and they are different. With the Range approach I get `{0.1, 0.125893, 0.158489, 0.199526, 0.251189, 0.316228, 0.398107, \
0.501187, 0.630957, 0.794328, 1., 1.25893, 1.58489, 1.99526, 2.51189, \
3.16228, 3.98107, 5.01187, 6.30957, 7.94328, 10.}` and using `logspace` I get

Comment: `{0.1, 0.226864, 0.369821, 0.530915, 0.712446, 0.917007, 1.14752, \
1.40727, 1.69998, 2.02983, 2.40151, 2.82036, 3.29233, 3.82419, \
4.42352, 5.09888, 5.85991, 6.7175, 7.68388, 8.77287, 10.}`. If I call the results `time1` and `time2` the ratio of `time1[[2;;-1]]/time1[[1;;-2]]` is a constant (as it should be). The ratio of `time2[[2;;-1]]/time2[[1;;-2]]` is variable. Please take another look.

Comment: @Pickett I looked at the `logspace` link supplied and have concluded that it only works when the starting value is 1.0. That may be what the designer had in mind,

Comment: @PickettThank you very much!

Comment: @JackLaVigne kale fixed this and updated his original question, and I updated my answer correspondingly so now everything should be alright. Thank you very much for reporting this!

Comment: @dimitris No problem :) I've just updated the answer with a better `logspace` function.

Comment: @JackLaVigne and @Pickett: I cannot arive at the same results when I execute `extractEqualLogTime` from JackLaVigne's answer. I get error messages `Nearest::dmtch: The dimension of ...does not match.` I guess I am missing something here:-)!

Comment: @Pickett Updated `logspace` works great!

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the workaround. Actually it's the transfer of above MatLab code in Mathematica's procedural programming. Thanks to Sector, because his comments made me work harder with it!!

I would appreciate now other ways of arriving in the same result which makes use of Mathematica functional or/and rule-based programming (and of course make the program better:-)!).

Here we go...

```
fun[\[Lambda]_] := 
 1 + 9*(1 - 
     E^(-\[Lambda]/
        10))(*the function to generate the date; \[Lambda] denotes \
times*)

xi = Transpose[
  N[Table[{\[Lambda], y[\[Lambda], \[Tau]o]}, {\[Lambda], 1, 200, 
     0.01}]]];(*data; xi[[1]]= time; xi[[2]]=copliance*)
ndp = Length[xi[[1]]];(*number of time data points*)
tf = Last[xi[[1]]];(*final time*)
logti = -1;(*log of initial time to sample; user's choice*)
dellogti = 0.001;(*log time interval to sample; user's choice*)
logt = Range[logti, Log[10, tf], 
  N@dellogti];(*equally spaced in log scale*)
tr = logt /. a_ -> 10^a;(*back to time scale*)
nr = Length[tr];(*number of newly sampled data*)
If[tr[[nr]] != tf, tr = Append[tr, tf](*add the final time*); 
 nr = Length[tr](*number of newly sampled data*);]
rcount = 1;
xo = {};
For[i = 1, i <= ndp, i++, 
 If[xi[[1, i]] >= tr[[rcount]], 
  xo = Append[
    xo, {xi[[1, i]], 
     xi[[2, i]]}](*copy data equally spaced in log time*); 
  rcount = rcount + 1]; If[rcount > nr, Break[]]]
Short[xi]
Short[xo = Transpose[xo]]
{Max[Differences[Log[10, #] & /@ xo[[1]]]], 
 Min[Differences[Log[10, #] & /@ xo[[1]]]]}
```

with outputs

```
{{1.`, 1.01`, 1.02`, 1.03`, 1.04`, 1.05`, 1.06`, 1.07`, 1.08`,<<19884>>,199.93`, 199.94`, 199.95000000000002`, 199.96`, 199.97`, \
199.98000000000002`, 199.99`, 200.`},<<1>>}

{{1.`, 1.01`, 1.02`, 1.03`, 1.04`, 1.05`, 1.06`, 1.07`, 1.08`, 1.09`,<<3284>>,196.79`, 197.25`, 197.70000000000002`, 198.16`, 198.61`, 199.07`, \
199.53`, 199.99`, 200.`},<<1>>}

{0.00432137, 0.0000217153}
```